# VBA - how to merge all csv files with adding file name in last column

Tags: excel, vba

My Code:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Sub InsertFileName()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim i As Long
  LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 1 To LastRow
    LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, LastColumn + 1) = "=CELL(""filename"")"
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can any one help me to solve my query, How to i merge all csv files in to one with adding file name in last column in all files

Comment: What is the error? Where do you want to place the filename (which file)? You only refer to the ActiveSheet. You declared two variables outside the function.

Comment: Why was my answer deleted?  Originally I posed to the wrong question, realized my mistake, deleted that, and posted here.  How is that considered 'post identical answers to multiple questions'?  Lol.

Answer (score 0):

1. You declared your variables outside the sub.
2. You were assigning the formula `CELL()` to the cell instead of the cell's value.
3. You are using the function `CELL("filename")` which only works when you have saved the workbook, I'd prefer `ThisWorkbook.Name` if you want just the name or `ThisWorkbook.FullName` if you want the path with the name.

```
Sub InsertFileName()

  Dim LastRow As Long      
  Dim LastColumn As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim i As Long
  LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 1 To LastRow
    LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, LastColumn + 1).value2 = "=CELL(""filename"")"
    'ActiveSheet.Cells(i, LastColumn + 1).value2 = ThisWorkbook.Name 'or ThisWorkbook.FullName
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```